# Manually rendered form fields do not save data

Tags: django, forms, save

I really wanted to figure this out myself and I spent over 4 hours on the subject but I give up now.

I have a form that is supposed to save data, and if I lay out the form with the {{ form }} tag everything works great. If I put in to form with individual tags like {{ form.client_email }}, the form data is not saved to the database.

I need to render these fields manually for front end purposes but I just couldn't figure out how to do it.
I appreciate your help a lot.

Here is my code.

views.py

```
def client_list_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            client_title = form.cleaned_data["client_title"]
            client_email = form.cleaned_data["client_email"]
            client_turkishid_no = form.cleaned_data["client_turkishid_no"]
            client_tax_no = form.cleaned_data["client_tax_no"]
            client_tax_office = form.cleaned_data["client_tax_office"]
            client_contactperson = form.cleaned_data["client_contactperson"]
            client_phone_number = form.cleaned_data["client_phone_number"]
            Client.objects.create(
                client_title=client_title,
                client_email=client_email,
                client_turkishid_no=client_turkishid_no,
                client_tax_no=client_tax_no,
                client_tax_office=client_tax_office,
                client_contactperson=client_contactperson,
                client_phone_number=client_phone_number
            ).save()
            return redirect("books:client-list")
    else:
        form = ClientModelForm()
    
    client_list = Client.objects.all().order_by("client_title")
    context = {'client_list' : client_list, "form": ClientModelForm}
    return render(request, 'clients/client_list.html', context=context)
```

Working template

```
<div id="clientModal" class="modal bottom-sheet">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <button class="btn">Ekle</button>
        </form>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Not Working Template

```
<div id="clientModal" class="modal bottom-sheet">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                 <ul class="tabs">
                    <li class="tab col m6"><a class="active" href="#gercek">Gerçek Kişi</a></li>
                    <li class="tab col m6"><a class="active" href="#tuzel">Tüzel Kişi</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="gercek" class="col s12">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                <div id="inline-form" class="scrollspy">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col m4 s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">email_outline</i>
                                    {{form.client_email}}
                                    <label for="{{ form.client_email.id_for_label }}">Müvekkilin E-Posta Adresi</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tuzel" class="col s12">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                <div id="inline-form" class="scrollspy">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col m4 s12">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                                    {{form.client_title}}
                                    <label for="{{ form.client_title.id_for_label }}">Müvekkilin Unvanı</label>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your "not working" template you wrap each of individually rendered field with a form tag. That's not the correct way to do what you need. Just keep one form tag like you do in the working template and render all fields inside:

```
<div id="clientModal" class="modal bottom-sheet">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}


            <!-- put your fields here with any additional markup you need -->

            {{ form.client_email }}
            <label for="{{ form.client_email.id_for_label }}">Müvekkilin E-Posta Adresi</label>

            {{ form.client_title }}
            <label for="{{ form.client_title.id_for_label }}">Müvekkilin Unvanı</label>

            <!-- by the way you can use form.<field>.label_tag -->
            {{ form.client_phone_number }}
            {{ form.client_phone_number.label_tag }}

            <!-- and maybe you'd also like to render errors -->
            {{ form.client_phone_number.errors }}

            <button class="btn">Ekle</button>
        </form>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Also, the ClientModelForm seems to be an instance of ModelForm, so you do not need to deal with form.cleaned_data manually. For new objects you can just call form.save(commit=True):

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(commit=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the cleaned_data trick, that part works. The form still does not work though. Even in the working template if I just change {{ form }} tag to {{ form.client_title }}, the post data is sent but not registered in the db.

Comment: @AhmetNecipArslan show your actual code including the form

Comment: `code`

<div id="clientModal" class="modal bottom-sheet">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.client_title}}
                <button class="btn">Ekle</button>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>

`code`

Comment: @AhmetNecipArslan you still do not render errors, are you sure your form is valid?